# Using AudioClip in Java freezes the program terribly?

Tags: java, audio

I don't have any code to show in particular to link because this is quite a general question...you see, I made a small game applet with 8 AudioClip variables, and these were supposed to play every time a certain action was taken by the user. Ex: Player clicks = Shooting sound plays. The thing is, the moment I added these AudioClip files my program just freezes terribly and becomes borderline unplayable if the freezing is particularly bad.

The simple way I did it is here (From the book, actually)

```
AudioClip playerShooting;

playerShooting=getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"PlayerShooting.wav");
```

Then I would just use the following whenever the user clicked:

```
playerShooting.play():
```

My program worked smoothly before I added these wav files. They aren't even that long. Where did I go wrong here, and, how can I remove the random freezing?

EDIT:

This is the code I am running:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if(playerAlive)
                    {
                        timeShotsAfter=System.currentTimeMillis();

                        if((timeShotsAfter-timeShotsBefore)>=100)
                        {
                            if(shotIndex<10)
                            {
                                playerShooting(); //Here is where I call the function
                                shotFiredX[shotIndex]=currentX;
                                shotFiredY[shotIndex]=currentY;
                                shotSize[shotIndex]=20;
                            }

                            if(shotIndex<10)
                                shotIndex++;
                            else
                                shotIndex=0;

                            timeShotsBefore=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                        else{}

                        toggleShooting=false;
                    }
                }
```

This is the function:

```
public void playerShooting()
        {
            new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        playerShooting.play();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Play the audio clip in another thread?
EDIT:

```
new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        playerShooting.play(): 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Edit:

I'm not quite sure if this part is correct:

> getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"PlayerShooting.wav");

Try adding `System.out.println(getDocumentBase());` to see whether the location is correct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with threads, but do you mean I should replace "playerShooting.play();" with your code?

Comment: He meant to call the play() method in the thread (i.e. in place of //PLAY AUDIO CODE comment).

Comment: @user3436981 Check the edit. This way each time a user clicks a seperate thread will be created to play the sounds and the main thread running your application won't be blocked.

Comment: Yeah I just updated my program, what I did is that when the user clicks I ran a function that had your code in it. Is that what I was supposed to do? I just tried it but it still freezes.

Comment: @user3436981 Post some code please in your question of what you tried.

Comment: Oh the sound is in the correct location, the sound playing is not the problem it's that the sound causes the program to freeze

Comment: guys... its java. what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem a while back. What I did to solve my problem was update to JDK 8. In previous JDK versions, audio files appear to have been an afterthought and can be buggy. If you are still having problems, JDK 8 has the ability to play mp3 files which are significantly smaller than wav (you may want to try this). Make sure you use `sound.stop()` when your clips are done as this might free up some memory.